# Trying to get FontAwesome working with jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I've been trying to add FontAwesome to work with jQuery mobile. After reading the replies in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809890/how-where-to-install-font-awesome-in-jquery-mobile-app

I tried to do as the most recent answerer suggested, adding .ui-icon before fa. Unfortunately it wouldn't work.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CLANQ/2/

```
    .ui-icon-fa-facebook-square:before {
        content: "\f082";
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas in regards to how it could be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `ui-icon-fa` class separately:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-icon-fa ui-icon-fa-facebook ... and other classes">Log in using Facebook</a>
```

Check out [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLANQ/3/)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the font seems to become Times New Roman? Any idea why that is?

Comment: which font exactly? I don't see any times new roman in the fiddle... maybe you use a very old browser? or maybe even an old IE version? :)

Comment: I'm using latest google chrome, but on Safari it's not Times New Roman. I think what it comes down to is that [code]ui-icon-fa[/code] makes the button use the FontAwesome font, is there any way to prevent that?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CLANQ/6/

Comment: ah yes, I see what you mean. It's quite easy actually: add an `<i>` element with the styles _inside_ the anchor tag. That way you only let FA style the 'icon', not the whole anchor. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/CLANQ/7/