# How to use font awesome icons in jQuery mobile buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to use jquery mobile with font awesome buttons, to do so, I followed the answer described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809890/how-where-to-install-font-awesome-in-jquery-mobile-app). However, when I try to use icons in my buttons, the class `ui-icon-fa` has `display: inline-block` and the button is not full width now. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: why are you not using font-awesome as it is : <i class="fa fa-car fa-fw">

Comment: because that produces the icon next to the text. I want the icon positioned at left like other jquery buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a bunch of classes as in the referred post, I would use the standard `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` and just place it correctly with some CSS:

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-fa"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>hello</button>

.ui-btn-fa {
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}
.ui-btn-fa .fa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}
.ui-btn-fa .fa:before {
    line-height: 22px !important;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tasqnjb8/)**

If you like the gray disk from the standard jQM icons, add a new class (e.g. ui-fa-disk) and the following CSS:

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-fa ui-fa-disk"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>hello</button>

.ui-fa-disk .fa {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039);
    border-radius: 1em;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tasqnjb8/2/)**

Comment: Unfortunately with this method the icons won't behave like native jQuery Mobile icons if you use special classes for alignment and other permutations (e.g., `ui-btn-icon-right`).

Comment: That's basically my point -- you have to write additional classes whenever you encounter a jQuery Mobile native class related to alignment, size, color, etc. With the Font Awesome to JQM conversation library I posted below, all of the JQM native classes work normally without the need to write additional custom classes.

Comment: @ElliotB. I did not see your post when I responded. That library looks good!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer won't work properly if you need to align the icons left, right or apply any other jQuery Mobile permutations (e.g., class `ui-btn-icon-right`).

I would recommend using the library created dotcastle and maintained in this [Github repo](https://github.com/dotcastle/jquery-mobile-font-awesome). The icons behave exactly like they would if they were standard jQuery Mobile icons.

Example usage:

```
<span class="ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-fa-500px"></span>
```

Comment: While I like your answer, and in general I would use yours, it has issues. First, it is very 'heavy' at 1.4mb for the library. Also, I found I had issues with it not adjusting to the text color. Using ezanker's answer allowed for lighter use, while having it adjust to the color set of the element. Thank you for posting it though!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: block` inline then.

Comment: Which container of the icon, I only have:
`<a href="ui-icon-fa ui-icon ui-icon-fa-user ui-btn....">text</a>`

Comment: You can use it on the icon itself

Comment: Just reset the display then, with 'display: block'

Answer (score 0):

For icon only buttons and default swatch with white icons i use this CSS.

**Example**

One with a very wide icon and a round icon. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djmj1000/rmv91d0s/)

```
<button class="fa fa-address-card ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"/>

<button class="fa fa-plus-circle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-btn.fa.ui-btn-icon-notext
{
    text-indent: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #acacac;
    padding: 0.1em;
    font-size: 0.8985em;
    height: 1.75em;
    width: 1.75em; 
    /* use inset box-shadow to simulate black background (:after) with opacity, which did blend white fa icons 
        default outset black shadow*/
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0.21em #f6f6f6, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    text-shadow: none;
}

.ui-btn.fa.ui-btn-icon-notext:focus
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0.21em #f6f6f6, 0 0 12px #38c; /* inset and default outset focus shadow */
}

.ui-btn.fa.ui-btn-icon-notext:hover
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0.21em #ededed, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);; /* simulate default hover with box shadow, default outset black shadow */
}

.ui-btn.fa.ui-btn-icon-notext:after
{
    background-color: transparent;
    content: "";
}
```

**Background:**

The initial approach is very simple but only allows black or dark font awesome icons  because jquery uses following rule to render icons. A white icon will blend out with this `after` transparent background. I avoid this using *inset* box-shadow instead.

```
.ui-btn-icon-notext:after 
{
    background-color:#666;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: "Update",
                                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                    return '<a href="#container" style="color:white" onclick="changeRM1(this)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="height:50px;width:70px"   id="button_' + i + 1 + '" type="button" ></i></a>'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).