# How to add a fontawesome 5.3.1 icon to Jquery Mobile elements?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I added the call to CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and in custom.css I tried with

```
[data-icon="pray"] { 
    content: "\f683" !important;
}
```

I also added the variables with :after, :before: content, but it did not.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid"><span>Detais</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-icon="pray"><span>Pray</span></a></li>
                
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested the examples, and I have obtained no results on the basis of these examples. None of them are related to Jquery Mobile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012650/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-jquery-mobile-buttons

Comment: The ones proposed by @temaniafif weren't for jQM.

Comment: @Omar and the one your proposed has nothing to do with font-awesome 5 and how they are used with CSS... it's a CSS issue, as the OP is not using FA 5 correctly

Comment: @Omar here is the code he need to use considering all the duplicate I added : https://jsfiddle.net/02znb9yx/ (if of course we take the time to read them)

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're correct. https://jsfiddle.net/02znb9yx/1/ Thank you for the clarification.